# Plot data set read by pandas with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am a python beginner. I generated data without a header and I read it with pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('histdata', sep=" ",names=['x', 'density'], header=None)
top = df.head() 
top
```

[image]

I thought it must be quit simple now to plot these values. I tried it with seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(x='x', y='density', data=df)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. No plot appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without specifying names in the read_csv method:

```
df = pd.read_csv('PATH_TO_FILE.csv')
sns.lineplot(x = df.columns[0], y = df.columns[1], data=df)
```

It works for me with a csv file in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Use plot function of dataframe, its easy to apply.

```
df.plot(x = 'x', y = 'density')
```